# Changing Text with Previous Quotation Marks

Tags: string-manipulation, text

I defined some variables as follows:

```
altura=15;comprimento=45;largura=92;
```

I have a TXT file that comes formatted from another application:

```
Import["C:\Users\Desktop\Text.txt"]
```

> [image]

The other application exports some variables with quotation marks (`"`).

I want to import this TXT file and swap the values ​​of these variables according to the values ​​I set previously and after changing the values ​​to be able to export them modified.

I would like to export the TXT file as follows:

> [image]

Only the texts with numerical values that I want to change.

The next part of the term does not want changes:

[image]

I tried to use `StringReplace`, but I did not succeed.

Could anyone comment?

Answer (score 4):

Here is your file:

```
file = "\"altura\"= 10\n\"comprimento\"= 30\nlargura= 50\n\"Altura@...\"= \"altura\"";
```

And here are your variables defined:

```
altura=15;comprimento=45;largura=92;
```

Here is a way to process the file:

```
table = ImportString[file, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> {"= "}];
tableNew = Replace[
  table, {{"altura", _} -> {"altura", altura}, {"comprimento", _} -> {"comprimento", 
     comprimento}, {"largura", _} -> {"largura", largura}}, {1}]
```

> ```
> {{"altura", 15}, {"comprimento", 45}, {"largura", 92}, {"Altura@...", "altura"}}
> ```

Here is a way to export the file backward manually:

```
ExportString[StringJoin@Riffle[Riffle[#, "= "] & /@
    (tableNew /. {s_String :> "\"" <> s <> "\"", n_Integer :> ToString[n]}), "\n"],
 "Text"]
```

> ```
> "\"altura\"= 15
> \"comprimento\"= 45
> \"largura\"= 92
> \"Altura@...\"= \"altura\""
> ```

And here is a better approach:

```
ExportString[tableNew, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> "= ", "TextDelimiters" -> "\""]
```

> ```
> "\"altura\"= 15
> \"comprimento\"= 45
> \"largura\"= 92
> \"Altura@...\"= \"altura\""
> ```

Comment: I added the `fileLocation` variable to make it easier to replace the original file text

Comment: Although its approximation shows an error with accented characters, I do not see problems in this. I just need to avoid them while creating the original file. Accentuations are not problems.

Comment: If no other solution comes up so early, your answer is already solving my problem

Comment: @LCarvalho You shouldn't replace the actual file contents with `fileLocation` because it makes the outputs shown in my answer non-reproducible. Actually I did should ask you before answering for providing explicit copyable file contents instead of a screenshot, as it is accepted here. Providing screenshots isn't an acceptable practice here, and a copyable example must be always given. So I revert your change and ask you to replace the screenshots with copyable inputs.

Comment: Thanks for informing! I'll be more careful about this kind of situation.